# Why doesn't custom javascript files render on my Meteor templates when they're placed in the client folder?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Ok so i'm new to meteor and I'm having issues rendering my custom javascript files onto the page. I thought you were supposed to place them in the client folder. But for some reason that is not working. I've also tried adding script tags to call in the js files but that doesn't work. The only way it works is if I hard code my javascript code at the bottom of my page inside a script tag. However I can't do that for every js file I have because they all have similar variables and what not.

This is my project structure for the client and the rest of the project.

```
client
  js
    main.js
    classy.js
    bootstrap.js
  stylesheets
  views
    login
    register
    search
server
  social-config.js
public
lib
  router.js
private
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor will combine all the Javascript files it finds that's not in `test/`, `private/`, or `server/` directories and set it over to the client.

The Javascript files that defines your helpers, routes etc goes inside the `client` directory.

But if you want Javascript files that you can reference as is, put it in the `public/` directory. You can then reference them with a `<script>` tag, but only inside the `<head>`. If your file is at `public/some/dir/myfile.js`, you will be able to reference it in your HTML using the path `/some/dir/myfile.js`

I'd recommend against this, and write your logic inside one of your `.js` files in the `client/` directory.

This is what I do

```
client/          <---- helpers + event handlers (your logic)
    lib/         <---- Third-party libraries
public/          <---- Reference as is, in the `<head>` - sent to client as an asset, not for normal use
```

Comment: Going by your advice, I added the script tags into my main layout page and I also added the .js files that correspond with those script tags into public and I'm still not seeing the functionality for my page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear (slightly misleading) in my first answer. Can you tell me what "custom javascript files" do?

Comment: Custom javascript files are plugins for my navigation bar That slides down. And each section in that navigation bar has its own separate javascript file. All the files in that navigation bar all have their own anonymous function to prevent global variables. if I ever showed you these files they all have very similar variables only difference is that the variables are holding different id's and classes.   Did that make sense?

Comment: I've done what @danyll has suggested to get 3rd party libs to work. Are these libs wrapped in an IIFE? (http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/)

Comment: Yes, these files are all wrapped in a IIFE. I need to do it this way because they all have similar variable names just different id's and classes

Comment: @ecuanaso Sorry but I still don't quiet understand your need, maybe if you tell me which plugin I can help you better. If it's a *library* that enables your navigation bar to slide down, put the library in the `lib` folder inside the `client` directory to ensure it is loaded first. Then, for each of your section, put it in an event handler for that template, where the event may be `hover` or `click`. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying your application to *.meteor.com ? if it is the case, remove "social-config.js" file from your distribution and try again.

I recently workaround an issue similar to yours, my application worked fine in my server but when deployed to meteor.com most of my user templates worked incomplete or not worked at all (specially with user functions).

Redeploy your application without "social-config.js" file and then configure your social buttons interactively.